# Imperfect shifting

Tags: sram

Have a bicycle with sram rival shifter and sram gx mech which I recently changed handlebars on with new gear cable. There is supposedly a 1to1 ratio here however the shifting performance is not great. I can at most use 10 out of 11 gears. My theory is that there is something which flexes in the gear line that cause this problem.

I don't think there any issues with my mech hangar as it worked perfectly a few days ago with another shifter.

Any other things that could be the culprit? Or tips to how to find the issue?

I just wrapped the bars with new and expensive handlebar tape so if possible I'd like to keep that untouched ;)

Edit:
Began from scratch and changed the cable. However the problem persists.

So I'm getting clueless now, only thing I haven't checked is the mech hangar alignment with the dag tool.

Seems like the issue now is gearing from the fifth to sixth cog.

Gears worked perfect on the older handlebar with an xo shifter. However since then I have changed the cassette and chain as well.

What's my next move? Can't let the bicycle win. :)

Comment: Are the gear cables routed under the bar tape?  If wrapped too tightly it can cause extra friction.
If you can only use 10 gears though it is likely something more basic like cable tension - best just to undo the cable at the mech end and start over.

Comment: Just to clarify - you changed the handlebars, bartape, and gear cable inner wire?   Did you change the shifter? ("it worked perfectly with another shifter")   Did you change gear cable outers?    Are they seated in the ferrules correctly ?   Does it change properly if you pull the exposed inner wire while slowly pedalling ?

Comment: Changed handlebars, shifter, cable inner wire and housing. Internally routed in the frame. Have no exposed wires to pull. They should be seated in the ferrules correctly. One change I did is that I added a barrel roll on the wire.

Comment: Note that high-count indexed derailers need a cable (and housing) specially designed for low stretch, to avoid this problem.  You may have gotten the wrong cable.

Comment: Hm. That might be it. I Currently have some noname brand from China I knocked off my neighbour. But darn it. Then I'll need to replace my handlebar tape.

Comment: Handlebar tape can be unwound and re-installed if done carefully.

Comment: Before you wrap up everything again, lash the rig together with adhesive tape and test it out.

Comment: Redid everything now. See edit.

Comment: One odd thing that can cause apparent shifting problems.  Was working on a bike last week and the chain was jerking at intervals, for no apparent reason.  After study I realized that a couple of the chainrings had gotten burrs on them (in this case probably due to a previous incident with a knotted chain).  A few minutes with a file took care of things.  In your case there might be a burr (or bent tooth) on one of the rear cogs.

Comment: It's a brand new cassette with a brand new kmc El chain. So I really doubt that. But I'll check. That also does not explain why I at most can use 10 gears out of 11.the only way I get it into the 11th gear is by pressing and holding the shifter by force.

Comment: Ok decided to eliminate all other possibilities an connected the rear mech with my old shifter. then there were no issues. Then I attached my new shifter to the next directly wit

Comment: ... Directly with the mech. And it still has issues with the 5/6th cog and I cs

Comment: Can at most use 10 gears. Sorry for the trippel posts.

Comment: Is it safe to assume the shifter is the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Gears worked perfect on the older handlebar with an xo shifter.

XO shifters were 9 speed and were matched with derailleurs that used the "SRAM (1:1)" actuation, which is a [pull ratio of 1.1](http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/).

SRAM rival 11 speed shifters are part of SRAM road series which all use a rear derailleur pull ratio of 1.3. (Yes 10/11 SRAM road derailleurs are interchangeable.)

SRAM Rival road shifter matched to a "SRAM (1:1)" rear derailleur will never work properly due to the difference in pull ratios.

Finally, which "GX" derailleur do you have?  I don’t know of any GX derailleurs that use the “SRAM (1:1)” actuation ratio. It was my understanding that the "GX" moniker was only used on 10/11 speed SRAM mountain bike derailleurs (see [full list](https://www.sram.com/sram/mountain/component/rear-derailleurs))?  A 10 speed GX mountain bike rear derailleur should be compatible with SRAM Rival 10 or Rival 11 road shifters as they all use a pull ratio of 1.3. An 11 speed GX derailleur (pull ratio 1.12) will not be compatible with Rival shifters (10 or 11 speed).

**NOTE:** An 11 speed GX derailleur (pull ratio 1.12) would have been close enough to work with a 9 speed XO shifter (which expects a pull ratio of 1.1), but will not be compatible with a 10 or 11 speed Rival shifter, which are both expecting a rear derailleur with a pull ratio of 1.3.

> **UPDATE** the OP actually had an XO1 (not XO) shifter which uses "X-ACTUATION" and should be matched to a derailleur with a pull ratio of 1.12.   SRAM Rival shifters expect a derailleur pull ratio of 1.3. This difference is likely causing the shifting issues.

Comment: Sorry. This is the shifter I had. https://www.sram.com/sram/mountain/products/x01-x-actuation-trigger-shifter

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion that the pull ratio is not equal., so I have ordered the shiftmate 9 in order to correct this.

Comment: For anyone interested in shiftmate 9. http://www.jtekengineering.com/shiftmate/shiftmate-9/

Comment: @netbrain Once you obtain and use the shiftmate 9, you can post an answer outlining whether or not it worked well for you.  This would be valuable info for the community.

Comment: The shiftmate 9 had been installed and is working perfectly. 

Answer (score 3):

Check your cable routing, have you found the right hole? This pictures the correct routing of the inner cable and pinch bolt on a Rival X1 11 Type 3 Derailleur, but this does appliy to other derailleurs from SRAM, both front and rear, mainly road though this no longer holds I think.

[image: Check your cable routing, have you found the right hole? This pictures the correct routing of the inner cable and pinch bolt on a Rival X1 11 Type 3 Derailleur]

I suspect there's a lot of people out there like this, but it's easily missed and poorly signposted error I've found on a few bikes before, the clue is in the cable seat washer groove - again a little hidden.

The picture below shows the wrong way, this will actually slowly decrease the pull as you climb into larger gears and by the time you're in the top 3 on the cassette it may appear "out" of sync, or walk onto the teeth, chime a single tooth, and all these other ways you can thing of describing it!

[image: Wrong Inner Cable Routing SRAM RIVAL X1 11 type 3 Rear Derailleur]

Here's a video too